# Pushing a Hamiltonian part into dissipative part in Lindbladian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, dissipation, open-quantum-systems

Suppose we have the following Lindbladian:

$$\mathcal{L}(\rho) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H, \rho] + \sum_\alpha L_\alpha \rho L_\alpha^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{L_\alpha^\dagger L_\alpha, \rho \}.$$

Suppose we have some noise $H_0$ in the Hamiltonian part so that the Hamiltonian term becomes $H + H_0$. For any Hamiltonian $H_0$, is it true that we can put the noise term $H_0$ into the dissipative part, i.e. is there always exist a set of Lindblad operators $\{ L_\alpha'\}$ such that

$\mathcal{L}(\rho) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H + H_0, \rho] + \sum_\alpha L_\alpha \rho L_\alpha^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{L_\alpha^\dagger L_\alpha, \rho \} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H, \rho] + \sum_\alpha L_\alpha' \rho {L'}_\alpha^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{{L'}_\alpha^\dagger L_\alpha', \rho \}$?

Comment: Why do you suspect that such a thing is possible? Is it due to the form of $H_0$? If so, add that information to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you ensure that the Liouvillian $\mathcal{L}$ with the new Lindblad operators $\{L'_\alpha\}$ is hermiticity-preserving ($\textit{HP}$, $\mathcal{L}(M)^\dagger=\mathcal{L}(M^\dagger)$) and trace-annihilating ($\textit{TA}$, $\mathrm{tr}\{\mathcal{L}_t(M)\}=0$), the Liouvillian permits a representation in Lindblad-form.

Let me expand a little bit and give some context. Generally, the partitioning between the unitary and dissipative parts in the Lindblad equation is $\textit{not}$ unique. In fact, there is an on-going debate on how such a "canonical" partitioning should look like, in order to properly define quantities like work and heat in open quantum systems.

One very interesting partitioning scheme is the minimal-dissipation partitioning by Hayden and Sorce [1]. Concerning your question, I think the interesting part is that any hermiticity-preserving and trace-annihilating superoperator $\mathcal{L}$ can be written in a pseudo-Kraus form

$$\mathcal{L}(\rho) = \sum_j \gamma_j E_j\rho E_j^\dagger,$$

where $\gamma_j\in \mathbb{R}$ (unlike in the original formulation, they are not strictly positive). Using that, and the above conditions on $\mathcal{L}$, one arrives at the form

$$\mathcal{L}(\rho) = \sum_j \gamma_j \left[E_j\rho E_j^\dagger-\frac{1}{2}\{E_j^\dagger E_j,\rho\}\right],$$

which looks like the dissipator in the Lindblad equation, but without the Hamiltonian part. However, $[H,\rho]$ for any (arbitrary) hermitian Hamiltonian $H$ is $\textit{HPTA}$. Therefore, as long as $H$ is hermitian, any dissipator $\mathcal{D}(\rho)=i[H,\rho]+\mathcal{L}(\rho)$ is $\textit{HPTA}$ as well, and it can be written in Lindblad form from the pseudo-Kraus representation.

(Note that $\gamma_j$ play the role of pseudo-Lindblad rates, and are not strictly positive like in the original formulation).

[1] Hayden, P. & Sorce, J. A canonical Hamiltonian for open quantum systems. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical 55, 225302 (2022).

Comment: Thank you for the extremely useful reference and comment. Just to make sure I understand your point: for any HPTA Liouvillain, we can always find such set of jump operators that satisfies the equation that I wrote in the question. But for general CPTP Liouvillian, this property does not necessarily hold. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Both your points are correct.